# hibernate: can not access key or value of a map in hql

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

Suppose I have the following class:

```
@Entity
public class CompanyImpl extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Cat,Flight> flightCats;
```

Cat and Flight classes both have a "name" property. 
How can I:

1. select a company named "Tech" along with its pair of map that have the cat named "Meow"
2. select a company named "Tech" along with its pairs of map that have a flight named "Ocean"
   ?

I think of something like

> from CompanyImpl co left join fetch co.flightCats fc where
>   co.name='Tech' and fc.cat.name='Meow'

but it doesn't work:(

Comment: Are you sure your mapping is correct? Shouldn't you have two @OneToMany relationsjips, one for Cat and one for Flight? And they should be a Set or a List, not a Map

Comment: No. Two one-to-many associations is not what I need because I want the advantage of getting a flight(value) by a cat(key) in java,like co.flightCats.get(cat) returns its flight. And I believe the mappings are correct because it is the standard mapping of a java map in hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions

If you read through the documentation you will notice that you can't do what you want. You can only select companies based on the contents of the map but you can't really subset the map along with the query.